# Trying to grab the 'save' from a dropdown option from a clone in Bootstrap and save the input to Local Storage

Tags: javascript, jquery

trying to save the input provided from the user in an input form that is cloned, so i want it to work for all the 'save' options, keep that text in local storage, and lastly to maintain that text in the input form even when the user refreshes the page, i've tried a bunch of different ways at my wits end, ha.  here is fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dalejohn33/24u3vxmp/13/

```
$save.click((f) => {
  var task = $("input:selected").val();   
  var getTask = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("input"));
  var setTask = JSON.stringify(localStorage.setItem("input"));
  console.log("text input has been saved");
}
```

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some tasks here:

1. Get the right input's value

```js
var task = $(f.target).closest('.dropdown-menu').next().val();
```

`$(f.target).closest('.dropdown-menu')` gets you to the dropdown and the input is `next()` to it.

2. `localStorage.setItem` accepts 2 arguments: (1) The key name (2) The data (You pass only the key).
3. 1. In order to set the input's value to the value stored in localStorage, you need to store each input as a different key (not just `input`).
   2. You need to iterate the inputs and set its value from `localStorage`.
   3. Since the value you store is string, you don't need to `stringify` / `parse`.

Another point is the inconsistency `name` and `id`. The first element (the one you clone later) has none. Also the `id` and `name` are different values because you increase it between (`length++`)

https://jsfiddle.net/moshfeu/kw8jfg1m/32/

Comment: Thanks so much, this really simplifies things, i just have two questions, where did f.target come from?  and the value is being stored as 'undefined' 'value' in local storage, how do i change that?  working on this now so maybe I'll figure it out, oh and how do i get the local storage to stay on the input box field after refresh?

Comment: (1) `f.taget` explained here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target. In my example the value stored how it should. (2) If it's not working in your code, please update your jsfiddle so I could check. (3) If the data stored well in localStorage, you should iterate through the inputs (lines 25-28 in my jsfiddle)

Comment: `f.target` sorry. @DaleJohn is that answers your question?

Comment: so sorry for my absence I got distracted by another project.  yes this helped immensely, thank you!